# Speed performance of picking unique value from binary matrix file

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, file

I wrote this code to read a square matrix saved as binary file, that it can be `int, uint, float` etc... to pick a value from the matrix at given row `y` and given column `x`.
Could this code be faster to pick this value, better than 20 seconds.
The maximum row and column number in matrix is 3601 for each one.

```
import struct

#convert x,y indexes of 2D array into index i of 1D array
#x: index for cols in the 2D
#y: index for rows in the 2D
def to1D(y,x,width):
    i = x + width*y
    return i


def readBinary_as(filename,x,y,file_type,width=3601):
    with open(filename,'rb') as file_data:

        #initialize, how many bytes to be read
        nbByte = 0
        #data type of the file, uint, int, float, etc...
        coding = ''
        if file_type == "signed int":
            nbByte = 2
            coding = '>h'  #2B Signed Int - BE

        if file_type == "unsigned int":
            nbByte = 2
            coding = '>H' #2B Unsigned Int - BE

        if file_type == "unsigned byte":
            nbByte = 1
            coding = '>B' #1B Unsigned Byte - BE

        if file_type == "float":
            nbByte = 4
            coding = '>f' #4B float32 - BE

        #index of my value in 1D array
        i = to1D(y,x,width)
        for each_cell in range(0,i):
            file_data.read(nbByte)

        #read and save the picked value
        my_value_pos = file_data.read(nbByte)
        val = struct.unpack(coding,my_value_pos)[0]
    return val
```

Comment: The title states "picking **unique** value" - where's *uniqueness* handled in  your implementation?

Comment: I mean, I don't want to read the whole file, just one value, at given indexes assuming the file as 2D array (because it is matrix data).

Comment: I have a doubt that this logic would work correctly. Let's say we have a matrix of mixed `int` and `float` numbers with shape `10 x 10`. If I want to get item at location row=`5`, col=`4` (24th item), why should it read `54` bytes, as that would be returned by `to1D(5, 4, 10)` call ???

Comment: The matrix is all int or float etc... no mixing at all, I am still beginner to such things.

Comment: Sorry, you have right, but this code not for general case, if you know nasadem files for DEM, I think, it works like I did  and tried. I dont want to read the same file as int then as float, no! there is file as float, other as int, etc... so stand in documentation with each file, my code recognize the corresponding type to be read with the extension of file, I switch that with my if statements

Comment: Ok, can you share how's the input binary file is created in your case? By `struct.pack_into` or some other way and how performance is changed after you applied `seek()`? (perhaps, there could a space for additional optimization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `seek()` instead of a loop that reads 1 value at a time.

```
import io
import struct

#convert x,y indexes of 2D array into index i of 1D array
#x: index for cols in the 2D
#y: index for rows in the 2D
def to1D(y,x,width):
    i = x + width*y
    return i


def readBinary_as(filename,x,y,file_type,width=3601):
    with open(filename,'rb') as file_data:

        #initialize, how many bytes to be read
        nbByte = 0
        #data type of the file, uint, int, float, etc...
        coding = ''
        if file_type == "signed int":
            nbByte = 2
            coding = '>h'  #2B Signed Int - BE

        if file_type == "unsigned int":
            nbByte = 2
            coding = '>H' #2B Unsigned Int - BE

        if file_type == "unsigned byte":
            nbByte = 1
            coding = '>B' #1B Unsigned Byte - BE

        if file_type == "float":
            nbByte = 4
            coding = '>f' #4B float32 - BE

        #index of my value in 1D array
        i = to1D(y,x,width)
        offset = i * nbByte

        # seek to byte offset of desired data
        file_data.seek(offset)

        #read and save the picked value
        my_value_pos = file_data.read(nbByte)
        val = struct.unpack(coding,my_value_pos)[0]
    return val
```

Comment: Woow! that is what I searched for, thank you, I will read more about this seek(), I liked it. Thank you for your answer. But I passed oddset as parameter to seek() instead offset, I think you wrote it wrong without intention

Comment: Corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which reommends using `lower_case` for functions and variables.

There is also a standard for documenting functions, called `docstring` convention, which is codified in [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

In addition, you could use `elif` to avoid checking all `if` conditions if you have already found your file type. Or even better, put them all into a dictionary. Note that this now raises a `KeyError` for an undefined file type (which is a good thing). If you don't want that, use `FILE_TYPES.get(file_type, (0, ''))` instead.

I renamed your `to1D` function to `ravel`, because [that is what this operation is called in `numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html#numpy.ravel_multi_index).

```
import struct

FILE_TYPES = {"signed int": (2, '>h'),
              "unsigned int": (2, '>H'),
              "unsigned byte": (1, '>B'),
              "float": (4, '>f')})

def ravel(x, y, width):
    """Convert `x`, `y` indexes of 2D array into index i of a 1D array.
       Assumes that the array is of one consistent `width`.

       x: index for cols in the 2D
       y: index for rows in the 2D
    """
    return x + width * y

def read_binary_as(file_name, x, y, file_type, width=3601):
    """Read the value at position `x`, `y` from array in `file_name`.
       Assumes that all values are of the same `file_type`
       and that each row has the same `width`.
    """
    size, coding = FILE_TYPES[file_type]
    offset = ravel(x, y, width) * size
    with open(file_name, 'b') as file:
        file.seek(offset)
        return struct.unpack(coding, file.read(size))[0]
```